# How can I disable a link in HTML at beginning and enable it afterwards?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML web page. The left side bar has come links for navigation.

The logic is that at the very beginning, most of those links (`<a>` tags) are supposed to be disabled.

Only after user finishes some operations inside the web page, those links are enabled.

So how can I achieve that? How can I disable `<a>s` first, then re-enable them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disable the functionality be replacing the href with some no-op like `href="javascript:;"` and  adding the real stuff later.

Or add a handler which supresses the default event (with `return false;` or jQuerys `.preventDefault()`).

Comment: thanks. could you please give me some more example. suppose I have `<a>` of step1 and step2. step2 is initially disabled. and after I click step1, step2 is enabled. Could you please give a code example of this?

Comment: @JacksonTale sure I can. Add some markup to your question so i can see what you already have. Also - do you use jQuery /some framework or just plain javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery `.preventDefault()`

Link - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

But you have to use it in if condition

```
if maxwords
   preventDefault
else
   return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not do it on server side. For example in ASP you can set 
`anchotTagId.Enabled = false;` on PageLoad and after user finish action that you need you can say `anchorTagId.Enabled = true;`